# C# Response Shows Download Unsuccessful Error on Android Browser

Tags: android, asp.net, mobile, download, response

I used `Asp.net` and `C#` to run this website and to approach mobile version, I used `jQuery` mobile. When I download via desktop browser is working fine and when I try to download via mobile, I got error

> Download Unsuccessful

How can I fix it?

Here is my code

```
protected void lbAttach_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (this.IsPostBack)
    {                
        string sRFP = lblRFPNo.Text.ToString().Trim();
        if (dsRFP(sRFP).Tables[0].Rows[0]["Attachment"].ToString() != "")
        {
            byte[] Attach = (byte[])dsRFP(sRFP).Tables[0].Rows[0]["Attachment"];
            string strfn = Convert.ToString(dsRFP(sRFP).Tables[0].Rows[0]["AttachName"]);
            string ext = Path.GetExtension(strfn);

            Response.Buffer = true;
            Response.Clear();
            Response.ClearContent();
            Response.ClearHeaders();
            Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + strfn.ToUpper() + "\"" );

            //BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(Response.OutputStream);
            //bw.Write(Attach);
            //bw.Close();
            Response.ContentType = ReturnExtension(ext);

            try
            {
                Response.BinaryWrite(Attach);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                lblMessage.Text = ex.Message;
            }

            Response.End();
            Response.Flush();
            Response.Close();
        }
    }
}

private string ReturnExtension(string fileExtension)
{
    switch (fileExtension)
    {
        case ".htm":
        case ".html":
        case ".log":
            return "text/HTML";
        case ".txt":
            return "text/plain";
        case ".doc":
            return "application/ms-word";
        case ".tiff":
        case ".tif":
            return "image/tiff";
        case ".asf":
            return "video/x-ms-asf";
        case ".avi":
            return "video/avi";
        case ".zip":
            return "application/zip";
        case ".xls":
        case ".csv":
            return "application/vnd.ms-excel";
        case ".gif":
            return "image/gif";
        case ".jpg":
        case "jpeg":
            return "image/jpeg";
        case ".bmp":
            return "image/bmp";
        case ".wav":
            return "audio/wav";
        case ".mp3":
            return "audio/mpeg3";
        case ".mpg":
        case "mpeg":
            return "video/mpeg";
        case ".rtf":
            return "application/rtf";
        case ".asp":
            return "text/asp";
        case ".pdf":
            return "application/pdf";
        case ".fdf":
            return "application/vnd.fdf";
        case ".ppt":
            return "application/mspowerpoint";
        case ".dwg":
            return "image/vnd.dwg";
        case ".msg":
            return "application/msoutlook";
        case ".xml":
        case ".sdxl":
            return "application/xml";
        case ".xdp":
            return "application/vnd.adobe.xdp+xml";
        default:
            return "application/octet-stream";
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't need to call `Response.Flush` after `Response.End`. Calling End flushes the buffer automatically.

Comment: The android browser (on some versions) will not allow downloads of content types that don't have registered intents on the phone, if there is no application that can handle the type of file it will fail, that is likely the culprit.

Comment: This problem sounds like it might have the same cause as a few other open questions on S/O.  See my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25418934/665376

Comment: Did you get final solution with final source code ? `Response.Flush, Response.Close and Response.End` ?

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue, file download was failing in Chrome. I just removed Response.Flush() and Response.Close() and added just Response.End() which worked